# Give notifications on specific time

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I created an app in which user can add events in calendar and I want to give user reminder about their event at specific time. Date and time is already specified in event. I want to set notifications for each event.
I searched about it on google and found about alarm Manager but I am confused on how milli second parameter works. Like I want set alarm for 7:30 PM but don't know how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

1. If a reminder is all you want to create, check this out [How to Create a Reminder Notification in Android?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-reminder-notification-in-android)
2. If what you are looking for is a whole app concept or rather a full tutorial on how to do this, please follow this guide -> [Android Task Reminder App [Source Code Included]](https://data-flair.training/blogs/android-task-reminder-app/)